# Blender 2.8: Grease Pencil Fill Brush Not Working

Tags: grease-pencil, 2d

I've been trying to figure out how to use the fill tool, but it doesn't seem to be working properly. Am I doing something wrong?
The build is 2.8 nov 2018.
[image: Tried to fill with blue]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about issues with unfinished development versions of Blender

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out. I have to pick the "Fill Only" or "Stroke and Fill" in the Surface Tab.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The confusion is caused by the default setting of any new draw brush material where the fill is set to 0.0 alpha which means it is transparent (it makes sense as you'll most often just want to draw a stroke without a fill). Therefore the 'color bucket' click doesn't do anything obvious besides just adding another stroke.

For proper use create a new (fill) material and change the alpha of the fill color to 1.0 or any other value greater than 0. You may want to edit the stroke settings, too, i.e. deactivate it for the dedicated fill material.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: Is this still an issue with the current Blender 2.82a release (and forward from that version)? If not, please specify in this answer.