# 2.8 How can I draw and fill a closed shape in 2D?

Tags: grease-pencil, 2d

I was drawing something in 2d today when 2 hours of work went up in flames as I couldn't fill in any colors.

Was this a bug/glitch within the 2.80 Beta, or am I missing something?

I would use the fill to fill in a space, fully enclosed, but it would just make a rectangle, and not work. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82188/fill-along-the-front-of-a-path-of-an-svg/82200#82200

Comment: I fixed it! Turns out fill isnt as useful as pencil/marker/pen. You can create a circle and that will fill it in. Thanks for the attempt to help me!

Comment: or fill with a material with fill checked

Answer (score 0):

[Blender 2.8: Grease Pencil Fill Brush Not Working](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123717/blender-2-8-grease-pencil-fill-brush-not-working)

Set the fill in the Properties panel > Material section (same place as you would set the material for a mesh).  It's a little **Check box**.